# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile-hidden

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, mobile

I saw the useful function of the "mobile-hidden" in the creation of emails in cloud marketing.
If I wanted to create 2 content, one for mobile and one for the desktop, how should I do to see it in the salesforce preview?
For the desktop (thanks to the mobile-hidden class) all ok, disappears from mobile

But I also see the mobile version from the desktop. I tried to put a `"display: none"` or create a class for it, but it seems to me that the preview doesn't work well.
Am I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create or use an existing class, that will prevent the mobile content from being displayed on desktop.

In the same way that the mobile-hidden class hides content on devices with x or less display width, you need a class that will hide content on devices with y or more display width.

Here’s a useful article explaining how to create those classes on your own: https://www.webdesignersacademy.com/show-and-hide-different-content-on-mobile-devices-desktops/